# reading a csv file and removing \n in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read a csv file and put the elements in an array but the last element of each row is being joined with the first element of the following row with a \n in the middle.  Here is the code:

```
f = open("read_file.csv", "r+")
lines = f.read().split(',')


f.close()
print lines

exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use the csv module in the standard library

```
import csv
with open('read_file.csv', 'r+') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in lines:
        # do your stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
f = open("read_file.csv", "r+")
lines = f.readlines()
print sum([x.rstrip('\n').split(',') for x in lines],[])
```